# Create HTML table using AWK/SED command on unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a file that looks like this. Is there any way I could format the file to how I want it to look like ? ( see below ) I used various verisons of sed/awk but it seems to not work. The purpose of this is so I can get nice tables on my file so when i send them using the mail command on unix it would print out a table by reading the html text. Thank you very much in advance for any pointers or direct help on how to do this !

```
File
    Candy Max Capacity
    Skittle 2293 1.72
    M&m 3420 2.57
    choco 294 .22
    sugar  246 .18
    Salt Max Capacity
    one 2293 1.72
    two 3420 2.57
    three 294 .22
    four   246 .18
    Candy Max Capacity
    Skittle 2293 1.72
    M&m 3420 2.57
    choco 294 .22
    sugar  246 .18
    TONS OF WORDS AND INFO HERE. TONS OF WORDS AND INFO HERE. 
    TONS OF WORDS AND INFO HERE. TONS OF WORDS AND INFO HERE. 
    TONS OF WORDS AND INFO HERE. TONS OF WORDS AND INFO HERE. 
    TONS OF WORDS AND INFO HERE. TONS OF WORDS AND INFO HERE. 
    TONS OF WORDS AND INFO HERE. TONS OF WORDS AND INFO HERE. 
    TONS OF WORDS AND INFO HERE. TONS OF WORDS AND INFO HERE.
```

Example of how I want it to look like.

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<table border="1" style="width:300px">
<tr>
<td>Candy</td><td>Update</td><td>Capacityt</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SKittle</td><td>2293</td><td>1.72</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>M&M</td><td>3420</td><td>2.57</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Choco</td><td></td> 294<td>.22</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Sugar</td><td></td> 246<td>.18</td>
</tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: If you have already made an attempt yourself, you should include it here and describe the problems that you are experiencing with it.

Comment: What happened to the `TONS OF WORDS...` lines? How did "Update" become "Max"? WHat about the other input lines - other tables or other rows or what? It's a trivial problem to solve but at an absolute minimum you've got to show us input and output that correlate to each other so we're not guessing..

Answer (score 0):

As the others have mentioned, you should really include your previous attempts and the problems with them. Anyways, here's my attempt at a solution:

`awk '{print "<tr>\n<td>"$1"</td><td>"$2"</td><td>"$3"</td>\n</tr"}' INPUT.FILE`

The quotes are very important because of how `awk` interprets the `<>` and the positional variables. You'll have to add the HTML header and footer parts manually but this should give the middle section. I'm sure it can be written more concisely, I'll keep trying for a better solution.

NOTE: This script will parse the entire file. I can't discern a start or stop point based on your original question except perhaps parsing only the first 19 lines. If this is the case, let me know and I can add boundaries to the `awk` script.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo ${header}
cat file | while read col1 col2 col2; do
   echo "   <tr>
      <td>${col1}</td><td>${col2}</td><td>${col3}</td>
   </tr>"
done
echo "</table>"
```